# How to make a shell script executed by xargs accept user input?

Tags: shell, stdin, xargs

I tried to use `find . -name "<pattern>" -print0 | xargs -0 sh` to execute several scripts with names matching some pattern. However some matched scripts need to get user input, say `read -r var`, the execution just ignore them without waiting for the input.

e.g.

```
% cat a.sh
printf "Input the value of var:"
read -r var
printf "var=$var\n"

% sh a.sh
Input the value of var:<my_input>
var=<my_input>

% xargs <<< "a.sh" sh
Input value of var:var=
```

Why does the `xargs` execution not wait for the input? Is there any way to work around this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: The shell script inherits its stdin from the pipe.  The shell inherits its stdin from xargs.  The problem is not with xargs at all.  The problem is that someone conflated 'stdin' with 'user input'.  If the shell script wants to read 'user input', it probably should read from /dev/tty instead of stdin.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thanks a lot. `read -r var < /dev/tty` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to  @William Pursell's comment. `read -r var < /dev/tty` fixes the problem.